# Why is Docker container able to access the internet?

Tags: docker, networking

I have a basic question about Docker that is probably due to lack of knowledge on my part about networking. The [Docker container networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) states:

> By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the --publish or -p flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host.

It sounds like, when you install a container on your computer without mapping any ports from the container to the host machine, the container should not be able to access the internet. However, for example, I install the Ubuntu container with:

`docker pull ubuntu`

Then I enter the container's command line with:

`docker run -ti ubuntu bash`

At that point, I can run `apt-get update` and the container starts pulling information from the internet without mapping any ports (e.g. `-p 80:80`). How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing a port allows machines external to the docker host to access the container, inbound connectivity. By default, containers can access the network with outbound connectivity.

To restrict a container from accessing the network, you can either run the container with no network (note: this still creates a loopback interface, and you can later connect it to another network):

```
docker run --net none ...
```

Or you can create a network with the `--internal` option and run containers on that network:

```
docker network create --internal internal
docker run --net internal ...
```

The internal network is created without a gateway interface on the bridge network.

Answer (score 2):

When they talk about publishing ports, they mean inbound ports.

Outbound ports work - depending on your network type - see here for more:

https://docs.docker.com/network/